# Cannot decode Json array as a List<dynamic> and getting error type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: json, flutter, dart

This my json array response body :-

```
[
  {
    "data1": {
      "subdata1":"subvalue1",
      "subdata2":"subvalue2",
      "subdata3":3,
      "subdata4":{
        "subsubdata1":"subvalue1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "data2": {
      "subdata1":"subvalue1",
      "subdata2":"subvalue2",
      "subdata3":3,
      "subdata4":{
        "subsubdata1":"subvalue1"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I try decoding it like this:-

`List<dynamic> response=json.decode(responce)`

but I get error:-

`'_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'`

How do I get this right?

Answer (score 0):

try `List<Map<String, dynamic>> response=json.decode(responce)`

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers and post a short explanation why your code works.